# Using simple Recursion to create a list

Tags: python, list, recursion, linked-list

I want every element in l(which is a list) to be added to a. 
When I run the function, it gives me '[]' every time. How can I fix this?

```
def sim(l):
    a = []
    if len(l)>0:
        a = a.append(l.pop())
        l.pop()
        return sim(l)
    return a
```

Comment: ```list.append()``` returns None.

Comment: @wwii, You should post that as an answer along with a suggested improvement or alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Code :`def sim(l):
           a = []`

when you call Function recursively `return sim(l)` every time it is call `sim(l)` and `a=[]` is empty.

Try This :

```
        def sim(l,a):
            if len(l)>0:
                 a.append(l.pop())
                 print a
                 return sim(l,a)
        return a
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Several things are wrong:

You shouldn't use lowercase L for a variable name - it looks like one

At the top of the function you assign an empty list to `a` - ultimately `sim` will be called with an empty list, then `a` will be assigned an empty list,  the conditional statement will *fail* and `sim` will return an empty list.

Inside the conditional statement you assign the return value of `list.append()` to `a`. The return value is None so whatever `a` was before, it gets wiped out.

Inside the conditional statement you `pop()` two items out of your *control* list

An empty list has a boolean value of false so there is no need to explicitly check its length,

```
def sim(el, a = None):
    if el:
        a.append(el.pop())
        return sim(el, a)
    return a
```

I was taught to write the base case of a recursive function as the first statement:

```
def sim(el, a = None):
    if not el:
        return a
    a.append(el.pop())
    return sim(el, a)
```

Answer (score 1):

`append()` doesn't return anything but does update the existing list.  In other words, by trying to assign the result of the `append()` method, you're setting `a` to nothing after you have already appended the item.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a homework assignment where you're required to do it in a certain (overly complicated) way? Because if not, you can add one list to another in Python like so:

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a = []
>>> a.extend(l)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```